# ASP.NET: Clustered environment communication Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, cluster-computing

I'm pretty noob with ASP.NET programming and i'm a bit confused on a problem that i'm facing right now.

We, as devs in my company, live in a clustered environment like the one shown in figure

[image]

Nothing really special.
You see, IIS Websites are duplicated on evry FrontEnd Servers. Business logic resides on BackEnds that are sitting, togheder with DB and NAS File system, behind a firewall.

So communication between the public space and the protected one is permitted only through particular channels, with particular requests, to particular IPs and Protocols.

Now, we were asked to build a site where the user can customize his own environment, upload images **that will be dispalyed in his HomePage** and other features.

In a classical configuration, a user upload an image that is written in a folder in the site root, and then the HTML refers to that image to populate whatever control to display it.
But, when a user connect to our site, the load balancer will choose one particular frontend that's not the same for evry session. 
So, a user will upload his file, disconnect and then come back only to find that his image is gone, 'couse the Load Balancer has routed his request to a differnt frontend where the image does not exist.

So the need to write a piece of code that pull the file from the NAS behind the Firewall.
The upload part is stupid, and i can understand it.

My problem is:
when the user connects to his page, how i reference in the HTML an image that's not on the machine the site is running on but on a completely hidden File system?

I thought of writing a WCF that serve the image as as a byte stream, but which ASP.NET control to use on the Page to put the stream content on, and How?

I Know that asking the experts community will bring me the best way to accomplish this.

Hope this is clear enough.

Thanks so much for the replays and excuse me for the bad english form.

Comment: Do you guys see the image?
I cannot see it, but I'm behind WebSense and I'm not sure if it's blocking it or there were upload problems.

Comment: The image displays fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using your file system for User Images, i would recommend you to go for some CDN solution like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or some other you like. This way you don't need to take care of where the image is stored or requested from, it shall always be accessed through CDN url(given when you upload an image on CDN programmatically), where url shall be in your database.Using a CDN releives you of many concerns that you shall face while storing at your location.

Even though if you don't like to use S3 , then your option is good enough to develop a simple WCF/WEB service to upload/serve the images.

Comment: This sure been a nice answere if only were not given 2 years later :)